# Application stops when the device goes to sleep mode

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, cllocationmanager

I am creating an application that uses location services.  In a background thread I am getting the location details using location manager every 5 minutes. After getting the location details I don't stop the location manager - `stopupdatinglocations`.

When I test the application on a device, if the device goes to sleep mode, after some time if I try to open the application it will start from first screen - it didn't start from the previous place.  This means the application was killed.

How can I find where it was killed and is there a problem with location manager?

Comment: Have you specified the location services background mode?  If so then you will continue to receive calls to your location manager delegate methods. Your app may still be killed but it will be relaunched for location events.  Significant location change works better in the background that standard location updates

Comment: Yes,i am getting te location details from location manager.But app is killed in background.And i set the property pauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically as NO.Is it create any problem?

Comment: Have you specified location background mode in your app capabilities (Info.plist) ?

Comment: I have found that significant location changes will be delivered indefinitely but standard location updates won't be - this is independent of your application re-opening from the first screen.  iOS will re-launch your app in the background to deliver a location and then terminate it again.  When you user launches your app from the icon it will be fully re-launched

Comment: So,how to avoid that relaunch

Comment: You can't.  It is how iOS works. You can save your app state before termination and then restore state back to the active view when you are relaunched if you want to give the impression of your app continuing to run.

Comment: But we don't know when the app killed by os.How can we store the state.Is it work when we set the pauseLocationUpdateAutomatically as YES

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html - `applicationWillTerminate`.  Are you using a "long running background task"?  If so, then don't.  You don't need it and running too long in that task will cause your app to be killed

Comment: But i am using location service to get the location details.

Comment: Yes, location background mode is independent of `beginBackgroundTaskwithExpirationHandler`

Comment: So Now what i have to do to get the location details in background

Comment: Instantiate a CLLocationManager.  Set your class as a delegate. Set Location background mode in Info.plist.  Done.

Comment: Can i run the location manager continuousy in background or set the pauseLocationUpdateAutomatically as Yes.

Comment: You can run the location manage continuously **but** unless you use significant location change mode you will find that location updates stop after an hour or two

Comment: Here is an example application that uses Core Location in the background - https://github.com/paulw11/LocationDemo